# Factorization of $\sin(\pi z)$ through Hadamard Factorization Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, weierstrass-factorization

Hadamard's Theorem states that: Let $f$ be an entire function of finite order. Denote the zeroes of $f$ by $|a_1|\leq |a_2|\leq \dots$. Then: $f$ gen$f\leq $ord$f\leq $gen$f$+1 where gen is the genus of $f$ and ord is the order of $f$. Furthermore, $f$ can be written in the following way:
\begin{equation*}
f(z)=e^{Q(z)}z^m \prod_{n=1}^\infty E_{gen (f)}\left(\frac{z}{a_n}\right)
\end{equation*}
where $Q(z)\in \mathbb{C}[z]$ is a polynomial of degree gen $f$, $m$ is the multiplicity of $f$ at $0$.

So far so good. However, now I read that $\sin(\pi z)=\pi z \prod_{n\in \mathbb Z^*}(1-z/n)e^{z/n}$ and I do not understand the formula:

As ord ($\sin(\pi z))\leq 1$, we know that $Q(z)=a+bz$ for some $a,b\in \mathbb{C}$, however, due to $\sin x/x$ being even and $\sin(\pi z)/z|_{z=0}=\pi$, we get that $e^{Q(z)}=\pi$. So far so good. $\sin(\pi z)$ has a zero of multiplicity 1 at zero, hence the $z$ in the product. Again, so far so good. But now comes the problem and my

**Question:** We have gen $(\sin(\pi z))=1$. Thus $E_{gen(f)}(z/a_n)=(1-z/n)e^{z/n}$ (due to the zeroes of $\sin(\pi z)$ being the integers. According to the theorem however, $n$ is only taken over the positive integers. In all the formulas, $n$ is taken over all the integers. Why?

Comment: There is no real difference. You can take $(a_n)_{n \in \Bbb N}$ as the sequence of all zeros (except the zero at the origin) and build the product $\prod_{n=1}^\infty$. In your case that would be $a_n = 1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, \ldots$. Or you define $a_n = n$ and build the product $\prod_{n\in \mathbb Z^*}$. The latter is more convenient in this case.

Comment: Oh my goodness! I am blind! Thank you! For some outlandish reason I thought the zeroes were only for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ instead of the negative integers as well.